# PHP Call another Domain PHP Script

Tags: php, cron

I have one domain that is running a cron job every 15mins.
I starts a php script and from that script I do some general housekeeping.

I also now need to get that script to run some other php scripts on other domains.
eg: 
www.domain2.com/this.php
www.domain3.com/this.php

how do I run these extra php scripts from the original domain?

Comment: Unless you control those domains and have access to the actual `.php` files from the original PHP script, you can't do this.  All you would be able to get is the output of those scripts.

Comment: can I call the URLs from one domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the other domain scripts with

```
   file_get_contents("http://www.domain2.com/this.php");
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one URL as a parameter of `file_get_contents`

Comment: I made a wrong copy-paste. I don't think I deserve a negative vote for that.

Answer (score 0):

If its really simple call to other URL. Add following to the end of your main server.

```
for ($i=2; $i < $totalServers; $i++) {
    file_get_contents('www.domain' . $i . '.com/this.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something which you want to run the cron from one domain to another domain.. Before that you need to have access to this cron from those domains from which you need to run this cron. You can do that by editing the cron tab of those domains .. lets day cronme.pl you want to run from the d2.com, you can set cron tab in d2.com ...

~Gururaj